# Remove 'replacement' if 'pattern` does not match, using preg_replace'

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using a function that is using `preg_replace` function as below:

```
function replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject){
    preg_replace("/^$pattern$/", $replacement, $subject);
}

replace('(\w+)/((\w+)/)?', 'name=\1&family=\2', 'Jame/');
```

I'm not able to edit `replace` function and just should do something with arguments.
As you see second pattern `((\w+)/)?` is optional and may not exist. I'm wonder if there is way to have a result with no `family` if pattern does not exist, it means that `\2` is empty.

So i should have:

```
'name=Jame'
```

**Note**
I can't change `preg_replace` signature or using alternative function duo to teamwork limitations. looking for a `replacement pattern` if exists.

Answer (score 5):

For [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace), do not make it optional, make it explicit. Handle both cases:

```
$pattern     = [
    '((\w+)/(\w+)/)',
    '((\w+)/)',
];

$replacement = [
    'name=\1&family=\2',
    'name=\1',
];

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, 'Jame/');
```

Another alternative would be to match all parts and then give them a name with a second array, but slicing that one based on the number of matches. Depends a bit in which field you want to do the replacement.

Comment: +1 nice solution, I always forget to option to use multiples expressions :-)

Comment: +1, there might be a shorter answer, but this is clean, clear and maintainable code.

Comment: I can't change preg_replace signature but this code is really functional for other issues, +1. question edited.

Comment: @OmidAmraei: After you changed your question, it can be clearly answered as: No, not possible. (You're doomed ;))

Comment: @hakre Sometimes saying 'There is no way` is the best, So post a new answer to accept it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should give `preg_replace_callback` a try (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

```
$name = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(\w+)\/(?:(\w+)\/)?/',
    create_function(
        '$matches',
        'return "name={$matches[0]}" . ( !$matches[1] ? '' : "&family={$matches[1]}" );'
    ),
    'Jame/'
);
```

This code isn't tested yet... just an idea

Comment: I'm sure `preg_replace_callback` could solve that but was thinking to use no other callback, because we're on a team work and i'm passing patterns through a function arguments. +1 for an alternative solution.

Comment: so I recommend the nicer solution from hakre

Comment: @OmidAmraei: Which is not really an argument against that. If you can call `preg_replace` you could equally call a different function (one that you write your own) that does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm not using `preg_replace` function, i'm passing arguments to a function and know that function uses `preg_replace`. I don't want to force implementer of that function to extend the function.

Comment: @OmidAmraei: Okay, that actually sounds a little different ;)